# Getting Firebase to work with OpenShift - any special config needed?

Tags: firebase, openshift

I have tried both using custom token and just firebase secret. But the same exact app works when running locally, but I cannot authenticate when running from OpenShift Node environment.

```
myRootRef.authWithCustomToken(firebaseSecret, function(error, authData) {
  log.info('Firebase Authed');
  if(error){
    log.fatal('Unable to authenticate');
    log.error(error);
    log.info(firebaseSecret);
    return;
  }
```

Is there anything else I need to do to "bless" OpenShift - The error I get back is

```
{"code":"INVALID_TOKEN"}
```

The only thing I can think of that makes the most sense is that Open Shift is blocking the ports for Firebase communications which I believe is WebSockets

Comment: Looks like you are getting a response. So it doesn't seem like a connection issue. The error is pretty clear. Make sure you are getting the right Firebase Secret and that it is valid

Comment: **Literally** duplicate of [Not able to Auth from OpenShift Node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36062499/not-able-to-auth-from-openshift-node)